# Cant access username before Intialization when I try to use an async function to call a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What I'm trying to do here is call the username from the database from the cookie, I tried to just call it though a regular function, but that doesn't work since I have to wait on the data. then after send the data to the webpage. but my issue is just getting the data itself.
I don't really have much experince with promises, so I'm trying to figure out what's happening here. thanks for the help.

```js
async function user(req, res) {
  let key = req.cookies['cookie']
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `key` = ?', [key], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error)
      }
      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve(results[0].username)
      }
    });
  }
  )
}

async function grabinfo(req, res) {
  res.render('dashboard', { title:'Dashboard', username: username});
  const username = await user(req, res)
}


module.exports.grabinfo = grabinfo
```

The Error

```
(node:1463495) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'username' before initialization
    at Object.grabinfo (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/modules/dashboard.js:45:58)
    at /home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/router/app.js:37:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:348:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
(node:1463495) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside                                  of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the                                  node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli                                 .html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1463495) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections t                                 hat are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: you're using `username` in the line ABOVE the declaration - seems obvious you need to swap the order of the lines ... javascript works top to bottom, not bottom to top

Comment: The error message is clear enough. The error has nothing to do with promises. You are using the `username` constant before defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function grabinfo(req, res) {
  const username = await user(req, res)

  res.render('dashboard', { title:'Dashboard', username: username})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says.
You are using the username constant before defining it.
javascript works top to bottom, not bottom to top so first initialize username then use it.

```
async function user(req, res) {
  let key = req.cookies['cookie']
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `key` = ?', [key], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error)
      }
      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve(results[0].username)
      }
    });
  }
  )
}

async function grabinfo(req, res) {
  const username = await user(req, res);
  res.render('dashboard', { title:'Dashboard', username: username});
  
}


module.exports.grabinfo = grabinfo
```